# Selecting element from dropdown menu using WWW::Mechanize in Perl

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to write a little program that selects values from a dropdown menu and submits the form in order to access to the next page, here is a snippet of the HTML page :

```
<form name='formulaire' method='post' action=''>
<select class="sel_box" name="MENU" >

<option value='val1' SELECTED >value1</option>
<option value='val2'  >value2</option>
<option value='val3' >value3</option>
</select>
<input type='image' value='' src='ok.gif' border='0'>
<input type=hidden name='numTab' value='3'>
</form>
```

I use select() and submit() as below :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();

$mech->get_local('test.html');
$mech->select('MENU', 'val3');
$mech->submit();
```

and I am getting this

No elements found for .//*[(local-name(.)="input" or local-name(.)="select" or local-name(.)="textarea") and @name="MENU"]

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe select a form first? `$mech->form_name('formulaire');`

Comment: That looks like an error from the $mech->xpath method.  Are you calling that somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a different error:

```
I don't know which form to submit, sorry.
```

Which could be easily solved by adding the following line after `get_local`:

```
$mech->form_name('formulaire');
```